# Android EditText - Text overlay issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, overlay

I am seeing a weird bug in my app and I was wondering if someone could help me fix it.  I have a simple EditText with some existing Text, if I move the cursor to the top and hit the Enter key it moves the first line down and on top of the second line.  I made a video to help with the visual of what I am seeing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJfTDjBxdT4&feature=youtube_gdata_player

The phone is a stock Samsung Galaxy Nexus.  I have tried to change the InputType to various other things but they all see to have the same issue.  Here is the layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editor_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.72"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    android:singleLine="false" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Is that right, layout_height of 0dip?

Comment: Yes because I used a layout weight it recommends 0dip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Jelly Bean issue with Hardware Acceleration here is the Google link:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38770

I verified that using the Software layer fixed the issue for me.